# Oracle SQL creating table to satisfy requirements

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Galleries often display several items from stock
with the same starting date and for the same period. They in effect create a Gallery
Exhibition themed around a particular artist, media or other theme.

i would like to record a numeric exhibition code as an
identifier, the name for the exhibition, the theme of the exhibition ( A: artist, M: media, or O:
other), the details of the artworks which are displayed and the total number of artworks
which make up the exhibition. An exhibition must contain at least one artwork.

i have tables gallery and artwork which contain the information that i need i.e gallery_id and artist_code/artwork_no ( a pair to identify what artwork it is since artist can submit in multiple artworks), hence ill be joining these two tables.

This means that technically multiple artworks in the stock can be part of the exhibition and i want to record that. This means there should be at least one artwork associated with an exhibition so there can be one or more than one artworks associated with an exhibition.

I shortened exhibtion_id to exhibit_id if that is confusing.
If i want to create a table so that if i search exhibit_id = 1 it brings up the artworks associated to it, what should my constraints be ? and how can i achieve
exhibition must contain at least one artwork
CREATE TABLE exhibit (
exhibit_id           NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
artist_code          NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
artwork_no           NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
exhibit_start_date   DATE NOT NULL,
exhibit_end_date     DATE NOT NULL,
exhibit_theme        CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
gallery_id           NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);

```
ALTER TABLE exhibit
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_exhibit_theme CHECK ( exhibit_theme IN (
        'A',
        'M',
    'O'
    ) );

COMMENT ON COLUMN exhibit.exhibit_id IS
    'surrogate key added to replace exhibit composite PK';

COMMENT ON COLUMN exhibit.artist_code IS
    'Code/Identifier for artist';

COMMENT ON COLUMN exhibit.artwork_no IS
    'Identifier for artwork within this artist';

COMMENT ON COLUMN exhibit.exhibit_start_date IS
    'Date exhibition in the gallery began';

COMMENT ON COLUMN exhibit.exhibit_end_date IS
    'Date exhibition ends';

COMMENT ON COLUMN exhibit.exhibit_theme IS
       'Exhibition Theme
A -  Artist
M -  Media
O -  Other

';

COMMENT ON COLUMN exhibit.gallery_id IS
    'Identifier for Gallery';

ALTER TABLE exhibit ADD CONSTRAINT gallery_painting_pk PRIMARY KEY ( exhibit_id );

ALTER TABLE exhibit
    ADD CONSTRAINT exhibit_uq UNIQUE ( exhibit_start_date,
                                       exhibit_end_date,
                                       gallery_id );


ALTER TABLE exhibit
    ADD CONSTRAINT artwork_exhibit FOREIGN KEY ( artwork_no,
                                                 artist_code )
        REFERENCES artwork ( artwork_no,
                             artist_code );

ALTER TABLE exhibit
    ADD CONSTRAINT gallery_display FOREIGN KEY ( gallery_id )
        REFERENCES gallery ( gallery_id );
```

Comment: Are you wanting Oracle to enforce the fact that a single artwork cannot appear in different galleries in overlapping date ranges? (Cannot be in two places at the same time)

Comment: im not sure what that really means, but this exhibition table is just to record that the artworks are part of an exhibition, i already have a table that showcases the displaying of the artworks in the gallery.

Comment: It means: I can currently create records that say artwork 1 is in gallery 1 from 1-JAN-2021 to 1-FEB-2021 and artwork 1 is  in gallery 2 from 2-JAN-2021 to 2-FEB-2021. Clearly this is impossible

Comment: What do you mean by "exhibit" - to me an exhibit is a single item in an "exhibition", but it's not clear if you are conflating these two terms because your words talk about "exhibition" but your code talks about "exhibit". Also, to me an "exhibition" takes place in a "gallery" and an "artwork" is an "exhibit" if it is part of an "exhibition". This means "exhibition" refers to the "gallery" (or can your exhibitions span several galleries?) and an "exhibit" links an "artwork" to an "exhibition". If exhibitions span multiple galleries, can artworks be moved between galleries during an exhibition?

Comment: I'd say, there should be three tables, the exhibition, the artwork and a table joining these two

Comment: Thank you, i have re-edited my post for clarifications and edited the code as well

Comment: I don't see why an `exhibit` needs to contain an artwork.  I can imagine a curator creating an exhibit first and then later try to acquire the pieces that are part of it.

Answer (score 0):

the artwork_no NUMBER(5) NOT NULL with the foreing key to the artwork table will do the job

Answer (score 0):

I'll detail [Turo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6053084/turo) comment:

- You already have the exhibit table (though I'd consider renaming it to "exhibition" for more clarity if possible)
- You already have the artwork table
- You should create a new exhibit_item table cintaining the columns exhibit_id (to identify the exhibition) as well as artwork_no and artist_code (to reference the artwork)
- Add foreign key constraints for the artwork (like those in your example above) and exhibit_id
- The columns artwork_no and artist_code columns in table exhibition, and the corresponding foreign key, are not needed anymore

Now you can "add" artworks to an exhibition by inserting records into the exhibit_item table, and the following statement will give you all information you need to show the "exhibition gallery":

```
SELECT *
  FROM EXHIBIT_ITEM AS EI
    JOIN EXHIBIT AS EX ON (EI.exhibit_id=EX.exhibit_id)
    JOIN ARTWORK AS AW ON (AW.artwork_no=EI.artwork_no AND AW.artist_code=EI.artist_code)
  WHERE EX.exhibit_id=...
```

Of course you may select only some specific columns, and the exact WHERE clause will depend on your detailed requirements.

If restrictions like the one proposed by [Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard) "do not allow a piece of art to be exhibited on overlapping exhibitions" are needed, they can be implemented using database triggers. But this is a different story...